# Same script does not work on different server

Tags: php

I am writing PHP script for Progress bar.

My code:

```
<body>
<div id="progress" style="width:500px;border:1px solid #ccc;"></div>
<!-- Progress information -->
<div id="information" style="width"></div>
<?php

if(isset($_REQUEST['sub']))
{
// Total processes
    $total = 10;

    // Loop through process
    for($i=1; $i<=$total; $i++){
        // Calculate the percentation
        $percent = intval($i/$total * 100)."%";

        // Javascript for updating the progress bar and information
        echo '<script language="javascript">
        document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML="<div style=\"width:'.$percent.';background-color:#ddd;\">&nbsp;</div>";
        document.getElementById("information").innerHTML="'.$i.' row(s) processed.";
        </script>';

        // This is for the buffer achieve the minimum size in order to flush data
        echo str_repeat(' ',1024*64);

        // Send output to browser immediately
        flush();

        // Sleep one second so we can see the delay
        sleep(1);
    }

// Tell user that the process is completed
echo '<script language="javascript">document.getElementById("information").innerHTML="Process completed"</script>';
}
?>
<form>
<input type="submit" name="sub" value="Go" />
</form>
</body>
```

when I test it on [this](http://demo.ankinfosystem.com/uploadfile/another.php) server it runs properly. But on [this](http://ddeskonline.com/test.php) server it show me "Process completed". after clicking Go button..

I Used same coding on both server...

what is my mistake ? Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not implement it in JS/Ajax? You are sending more then 640Kb just for progressbar...if $total = 100 then it's about 6MB.BTW second server may use some buffering technique which ignore your flush().

Answer (score 0):

The php.ini on the server as of in PHP 5.3.0 may exclude cookies from `$_REQUEST`, so it might be the php.ini on the server that needs to be edited correspondently.

If You don't have ability to edit php.ini, use `$_POST` / `$_GET` etc instead of `$_REQUEST`.

If You don't know which way Your variable is sent, use something like this:

```
switch($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
    case 'GET': $the_request = &$_GET; break;
    case 'POST': $the_request = &$_POST; break;
    default:
}
```

It might also be the `flush()` function that does not work due to php.ini settings. See user comments under [php.net flush() reference](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.flush.php) - some recommendations about how to edit php.ini to make it work are listed there.